# How to block a link from a page

Tags: javascript

our HR dept. made a survey on surveymonkey.com and we use infokiosks/ Chrome browser in hq and in our stores, as well. 
At the end of the survey is a link to SurveyMonkey and I want to block the access to this link because in this way the user can escape from survey page into internet.
I've tried to do this into an iframe, no result.
If you have any idea how to solve this, will be much appreciated!

Thank you, Mircea.

Comment: do you know if you are able to run js script in the survey iframe?

Comment: Yes, I do . The problem is that is a SEND button at the end of the survey and the survey is set to return to main page after that. I want to block or to cover only the SurveyMonkey link from touching ( nothing to happen when you touch the screen in link area).

Comment: Is that really a matter of programming ? Why not setting up  a proxy/whatever to achieve this ?

Comment: You should be configuring the kiosk to disallow access to anything but a whitelisted set of URLs, probably using a proxy. This is not something you should be solving on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Removing SurveyMonkey branding is only available on **some paid plans**

Comment: So, basically I want to place a div floating over main page to cover the link. It is possible to ad this layer and the page flow under it?